# From matrix to 3D array

Tags: r, data.table

I have a table with three columns (Table 1):

```
id feature1 feature2
1   0.5       0.7
1   0.52      0.72
1   0.5       0.7
1   0.3       0.7
21  0.5       0.3
21  0.5       0.3
21  0.5       0.3
21  0.5       0.3
```

For each id I have four time points for feature 1 and feature 2. From this table I want to build a 3D array [number of ids, 4 (timesteps),2 (number of features)]. To do this I have the following code:

```
trainData <- array(numeric(),c(0,4,2))
for(patient in 1:dim(ids)[1]  ){
  trainData<-abind(trainData,TABLE1[id==ids[patient],-c('id')],along=1)
}
```

ids is a table with the unique values of 'ids' of TABLE 1. This code is extremely slow, how can I get the same result but much faster?

I expect the following solution:

```
  , , feature1

       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]  0.5 0.52  0.5  0.3
 [2,]  0.5 0.50  0.5  0.5

 , , feature2

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]  0.7 0.72  0.7  0.7
 [2,]  0.3 0.30  0.3  0.3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you wanted to continue to use the **abind** package, you could simply do:

```
feature.list <- split(TABLE1[2:3], TABLE1$id)
feature.array <- abind(feature.list, along = 3)
```

This produces a numeric array with conveniently labeled dimensions, no looping needed:

```
, , 1

  feature1 feature2
5     0.50     0.70
6     0.52     0.72
7     0.50     0.70
8     0.30     0.70

, , 21

  feature1 feature2
5      0.5      0.3
6      0.5      0.3
7      0.5      0.3
8      0.5      0.3
```

If `TABLE1` is a data.table, @Blaza points out that one can use data.table's `split` method to prepare the data frame for `abind`:

```
feature.list <- split(TABLE1, by = "id", keep.by = FALSE)
```

Finally, to produce your desired shape, you can use `aperm`:

```
feature.array <- aperm(feature.array, c(3,1,2))

, , feature1

     5    6   7   8
1  0.5 0.52 0.5 0.3
21 0.5 0.50 0.5 0.5

, , feature2

     5    6   7   8
1  0.7 0.72 0.7 0.7
21 0.3 0.30 0.3 0.3
```

Comment: +1 Just, as the OP is using `data.table`, it should be `feature.list <- split(TABLE1, by = "id", keep.by = FALSE)`, to achieve the needed result.

Comment: Thanks for the post. With your code I got a array with dim dim(feature.array) - 4 2 2. But I want an array with dim 2 4 2

Comment: Use `aperm(feature.array, c(3,1,2))`